# How to get an "average" of a distribution with no average

Tags: statistics, means, median, distribution-tails

Modelling something where I need some sort of average time, I reached Pareto Distribution, and the PDF is

$$
R(t)=\begin{cases}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi t^{3}}}, & \text{for } t > \frac{2}{\pi}\\
0 & \text{for } t \leq \frac{2}{\pi}
\end{cases}
$$

This is a heavy tailed distribution with an undefined (or $\infty$) mean. Median is also useless to approximate "average" behaviour. Median time, let's call it $\tau_M$ only gives the "approximate time" my event happens with 50% probability, but if it doesn't happen within the first $\tau_M$ seconds, the chance of it happening within the next $\tau_M$ seconds is less than 50%.

Then I said, I can model two events happening, one following the other. The PDF would probably look like

$$
R^2(t)=\int_{\frac{4}{\pi}}^{t} R(\tau)R(t-\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau.
$$

Wolfram Alpha was gracious enough to give me $R^2$:

$$
R^2(t)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi}\frac{(\pi t-4)}{t^2\sqrt{\pi t-2}}u(t-\frac{4}{\pi}),
$$
where $u()$ is the Heaviside function.

I thought that this might have a mean value, which means I am done, but it doesn't have a mean. Still, the median of this distribution would help me a little better. It still gives the time that two of these events happen with 50% probability.

Then, theoretically, I believe I might do better by modelling for $k$ events, each following the other one.

$$
R_{k}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\underbrace{\left(R(t)\ast\dots\ast R(t)\right)}_{k\text{ times}},
$$

and $\tau_{M_k}$ being the median of this distribution, I thought I might get what I want through dividing it by $k$ for a large $k$.

How reasonable is this? Can I use $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{k}\tau_{M_k}$ as a reasonable replacement for "average"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the lack of an average means exactly that this limit doesn't exist. That being said, what property of an average do you want to replace?

Comment: @MishaLavrov My gut feeling agrees with you about the existence of that, yet for a large but finite $k$, I might learn something about the process. I am currently preparing some simulations to see if $\tau_{M_k}$s approach to something as $k$ increases.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I want to approximate the number of times this event happens in a given time frame. I can't use PPP, I can't take the mean and divide it with the time. There is little I can do here without approximation, other than preparing convolutions for large $k$s and then say "this event probably happened $k$ times within the first $t$ seconds with a probability of 95%".

Comment: Wait, if $R(t)$ is the distribution of times between one event and the next, then $N_t$ - the number of events in an interval of time $t$ - has a perfectly good expected value. In fact, $N_t$ is not just a discrete random variable, but a finite one, since we have $0 \le N_t \le \frac{t}{2/\pi}$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov No, $R(t)$ is the probability of the event happening at time $t$. It doesn't even know if there is a next event.

Comment: Then can you describe the process in which it makes sense to count the number of times this event happens in a given time frame? (Also, I assume you mean *probability density* in your statement just now.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov $R(q)$ is the probability of a Brownian particle making contacts with a reflective boundary at time step $q$, if the particle is only one space step away from the boundary. It works as good as the Stirling approximation, i.e., not too good for a small $q$. I will move into time domain rather than time step domain, so there is a constant $\sqrt{\Delta{t}}$ somewhere, but it is no concern for this specific problem.

Comment: I feel like in that case your problem is that $R(t)$ does not give you a complete description of what's going on. I'm not sure what the expected value would even tell you if it existed.

Comment: @MishaLavrov no, $R(t)$ is perfectly validated through simulations. It is indeed *probability density*, as I have stated in the question. It also makes perfect sense that it doesn't have a mean, because each time the particle moves away from the boundary, it is less probable to hit the boundary.